# Accepting a Byte array, vb6 to C# interop

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, interop

I am doing an application that comunicates vb6 with a cryptographic wrapper. The .net and interop part, up to now, is alright, fully working.
As my client is testing It, I just have a quick question:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public SomeObjectComVisible GetThat(byte[] array){ ... }
```

I used, until now, either types that I exposed to com or int and string, and no problems until now.

Is it ok to use (.net) `byte` or chould I use `*char`?
When I mark the assembly to be visible and register to com interop, it creates a wrapper for it, or should I use some unmanaged type?

Ah, it is a vb6, not vbscript.

thanks a million

for those who seek the answer:

```
public SomeObjectComVisible GetThat([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_UI1)]byte[] array)
```

the problem is with arrays.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx

Any non bittable type can be a chore. You can specify your own types so they are used, you just have to make use of

```
[ComVisible(true), 
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ProgId("SomeNamespace.SomeClass"),
Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")]
```

on top of the class

Thank you very much you all.

Great help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marshaling of arrays is something I struggle with often when dealing with COM clients of my .Net code.  This article I find very useful in helping me understand the process.

[Blittable and Non-Blittable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx)

Specifically you can look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx) which talks about arrays

*Note: part of my original answer which we found to be incorrect*

> So from looking at that it looks like "**byte**" isn't blitable yet
>   "**Byte**" is.  If you switch to Byte[] it will likely work the way
>   you expect it to.  Note: char isn't blitable but Char is.

Comment: 'byte' is a C# synonym for System.Byte - they are one and the same thing

Comment: Wow, good to know! thanks man I wish I could give you two more ups!

Comment: almost... if that were true both "enum SomeEnum: byte" and "enum SomeEnum : Byte" would work... but only the former does... they may be effectively the same type but the compiler treats them differently.  Not sure if this affects COM marshaling or not.

Comment: Amazingly enough, the documentation on msdn was great. as it seems I should use for arrays this:  public SomeObjectComVisible GetThat([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_UI1)]byte[] array)

Comment: In VB.NET it is a Byte, but it is just syntax.  It is still an 8-bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:-

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public SomeObjectComVisible GetThat([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] byte[] array){ ... }
```

If that doesn't work, you can try different values of the `UnmanagedType` enum to see if you can find one which works.

Alternatively, you may have to mark the parameter as a ref, i.e.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public SomeObjectComVisible GetThat(ref byte[] array){ ... }
```

(Or perhaps a combination of the above.)

NOTE - make sure you regenerate the .tlb file after each change.

Comment: Thnaks a million, I put a post build event that recreates it every time! But Thanks for reminding me and for the anwser

Comment: I don't think ref byte[] is what you want, as that is an extra layer of indirection.  Arrays are already a pointer type (as in you are passing a pointer to the array memory).

Comment: Man these two answers were great, when I got the two together, I've found my answer. [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_UI1)]byte[] array

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread, but for VB.NET to VB6, e.g. ByRef bytes as Byte() works a treat. If ByRef is omitted and bytes is passed ByVal (the default), VB6 throws a "Function marked as restricted or uses a type not supported in Visual Basic" error.